# How to fix network issue with router/modem combo with an extra router?

Tags: networking, router, modem

Recently my ISP changed my modem which worked without issues for years to a modem/router unit. The modem was located in the corner of the house connected to a router in the center of the house which gave no problem at all regarding wifi signal. When the modem was changed to a modem/router the signal didn't cover the whole house, so I decided to use the modem/router as modem and connect to the router I've been using for years.

The modem/router interface is very simple. I just logged on to the interface with default ip 192.168.0.1 and changed mode from Router Mode to Modem mode. This automatically changes the modem interface IP to 192.168.100.1. That's all I did.

The Dlink router, I did a factory reset and connected it to the Modem. Dlink interface default IP 192.168.0.1. So I logged in to dlink interface, went to wireless network settings and just added a password for securing the network. That's all I did.

The thing is the system is working perfectly for some hours, maybe 1 day or 2, then the internet connection slows down from 40 mb to 0.5 to 1 mb. Everything is working, but really slow. The way I fix it is by rebooting the router. I just go the the router's web interface, reboot the router, and then the speed is up again to 40 mb for some time until the same thing happens again.

About the connections the modem has only ethernet ports 1-4. The Dlink router has Internet port and 1-4 ports. The cable I have is running from Modem port 1 to Dlink Router Internet port.

I've been trying to find what the problem may be, but it doesn't make any sense how it works perfectly then the speed just gets really slow, and it gets fixed by just rebooting the router. I don't even have to do anything to the modem. It's not that of an big issue but the thing worked perfect for years and now it gives problems every other day.

I would sincerely appreciate any help or suggestions with fixing this issue. Thanks.